# Proper approach to create hypermedia in c# webapi

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api2, hateoas, hypermedia

I'm doing some research on how to implement hypermedia for a particular resource, but can't find a real implementation example, just abstractions...

You know, in various articles, the guy create a method like:

```
public List<Link> CreateLinks(int id)
{
    ...//Here the guy put these three dots, whyyyyyyyyyy?
}
```

What I have so far:

```
public Appointment Post(Appointment appointment)
    {
        //for sake of simplicity, just returning same appointment
        appointment = new Appointment{
            Date = DateTime.Now,
            Doctor = "Dr. Who",
             Slot = 1234,
            HyperMedia = new List<HyperMedia>
            {
                new HyperMedia{ Href = "/slot/1234", Rel = "delete" },
                new HyperMedia{ Href = "/slot/1234", Rel = "put" },
            }
        };

        return appointment;
    }
```

And the Appointment class:

```
public class Appointment
{
    [JsonProperty("doctor")]
    public string Doctor { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("slot")]
    public int Slot { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("date")]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("links")]
    public List<HyperMedia> HyperMedia { get; set; }
}

public class HyperMedia
{
    [JsonProperty("rel")]
    public string Rel { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("href")]
    public string Href { get; set; }
}
```

Is there a proper way to that? I mean, without hard coding the links? How to create them dynamically for a given type, i.e. Appointment class?

I'm using c# Webapi, not c# MVC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. For adding routes dynamically to the HyperMedia collection you can make use of route naming:

   - Define your route with a specific name (for example for deletion):

     ```
     [Route("{id:int}", Name = "AppointmentDeletion")]
     public IHttpActionResult Delete(int slot)
     {
         //your code
     }
     ```
   - Use it by [UrlHelper.Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Web.Http.Routing.UrlHelper.Link);k(SolutionItemsProject);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true) method:

     ```
     public Appointment Post(Appointment appointment)
     {
         appointment = new Appointment
         {
             HyperMedia = new List<HyperMedia>
             {
                 new HyperMedia
                 { 
                     Href = Url.Link("AppointmentDeletion", new { slot = 1234 }), 
                     Rel = "delete" 
                 }
             }

         return appointment;
     };
     ```
2. It is also possible to add links dynamically to a result object without declaring the HyperMedia property for every class:

   - Define a class without links:

     ```
     public class Appointment
     {
         [JsonProperty("doctor")]
         public string Doctor { get; set; }

         [JsonProperty("slot")]
         public int Slot { get; set; }

         [JsonProperty("date")]
         public DateTime Date { get; set; }
     }
     ```
   - Define an extension method:

     ```
     public static class LinkExtensions
     {
         public static dynamic AddLinks<T>(this T content, params object[] links)
         {
             IDictionary<string, object> result = new ExpandoObject();

             typeof (T)
                 .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
                 .ToList()
                 .ForEach(_ => result[_.Name.ToLower()] = _.GetValue(content));

             result["links"] = links;

             return result;
         }
     }
     ```
   - Use it:

     ```
     public IHttpActionResult Post(Appointment appointment)
     {
         return Ok(appointment.AddLinks(new HyperMedia
         { 
             Href = Url.Link("AppointmentDeletion", new { slot = 1234 }), 
             Rel = "delete" 
         }));
     }
     ```

Comment: Thanks. So my model is not so for away... Answer accepted.

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely extract the `Rel` into an `Enum` (2 in fact, a Standard one - `Delete`, `Put` etc - and a custom one - the latter could contain custom relationships like `customer-by-id`).

You can also build the `Href` params dynamically (pull the parameters from the object's properties), but as for the resource itself...you're probably stuck with hardcoding that (you could also look into reflection).

Comment: Thanks, plus 1 for the help. I'll take that into mind.